# Can we found if Response.Write is delivered to user in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I know that we can send a response with Response.Write but my problem is how can I found if this Response is delivered to the user, or no? (i.e. network connection lost, canceled by user, or other reason)

**UPDATE**
Let me say my senario, i have mobile app that user can send message to other user by query string, all things is ok, now becuse other user get this puted message, mobile app will send request somthing like :
GetMessage.aspx?MyID=....
this page will not send response to user until time out or new message received:

```
manualResetEvent.WaitOne(10000);
```

after that server will fetch new record for user that called GetMessage.aspx?MyID=....
and delete that record...
and server will call Response.Write(fetched record)

now if server is in manualResetEvent.WaitOne(10000); state, and user disconnected from network or... server will fetch record and so on...

the message will fetch and Write.Response will call and because i cannot found is Write.Response sent to user (delivered) the fetched message will lost...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It doesn't work that way.

Comment: i am edit my question, to know what i want to to, thanks

Comment: Is this a mobile web application, using a browser, or is it a native application? Most likely, you need to read about AJAX.

Comment: no some thing like WeChat, Viber, oovoo apps, no browser using, all request will send something like AJAX Request, i use httpclient and HttpPost in my android app

Comment: Then you either won't be using Response.Write, or it will be just a part of the response. Think in terms of AJAX.

Comment: i know AJAX but i dont't know what do you mean about it, response is not part of content, response is all of content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `Response.Write` is not *delivered* to the user. It produces part of the response to the user. This is a stream of bytes. You can't tell when one byte is returned to the user versus when the next byte is returned to the user.